# Replace `if/guard let` with two values in a single functional instruction

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I’m looking for a way to replace an `if let` (or `guard let`) test by its **functional** counterpart in **Swift**. I just can’t find a way to do it, maybe it’s just not possible, but I’m curious about it.

So I have this code :

```
struct Example {
    var first: String? = "First"
    var second: String? = "Second"

    var concat: String? {
        guard let first = first, let second = second else {
            return nil
        }

        return first + second
    }
}

var example = Example()
example.concat // FirstSecond

example.first = nil
example.concat // nil
```

What I want is `concat` variable to be `nil` if any of first or second is `nil`. This is what above code is doing. I was thinking about how to make it **functional** *rainbows*.

I came up with this, but I’m not satisfied because I need explicit parameters names on my `flatMap` and I’m wondering if there’s a cleaner solution (implying chaining of map or something like this) :

```
struct Example {
    var first: String? = "First"
    var second: String? = "Second"

    var concat: String? {
        return first.flatMap { f in second.map { s in f + s } }
    }
}

var example = Example()
example.concat // FirstSecond

example.first = nil
example.concat // nil
```

I thought about tuples but it always implies using an intermediate type like `Array`, doesn’t feel very clean to me.

**EDIT 1 :** Finally, please take into account that this example is using `String` but I’d like to find a solution that would work with any `Optional` type.

My **ideal solution** would look like this :

```
var concat: String? {
    return (first, second).map { $0 + $1 }
}
```

But this is not possible because we can’t define functions for tuples.

**EDIT 2 :** The closest (from my ideal solution) code I got was to define a global function (not really clean) like this :

```
func opMap<T>(_ tuple: (T?, T?), transform: (T,T) -> T?) -> T? {
    guard let one = tuple.0, let two = tuple.1 else { return nil }
    return transform(one, two)
}

var concat: String? {
    return opMap((first, second)) { $0 + $1 }
}
```

Another limitation appears here, I can only work with pairs of values. My ideal solution would also work with any number of values.

**EDIT 3 :** As proposed by @Hamish in comments this is an interesting way to solve the problem using an `Optional` extension :

```
extension Optional {
    func map(with: Wrapped?, transform: (Wrapped, Wrapped) -> Wrapped?) -> Wrapped? {
        guard case .some(let first) = self, let second = with else { return nil }
        return transform(first, second)
    }
}

var concat: String? {
    return first.map(with: second) { $0 + $1 }
}
```

**EDIT 4 :** (yeah I love edits) @Martin R proposed an improvement on previous solution which is even more close to what I want (because we have independent types for first, second and result), see below :

```
extension Optional {
    func map<T, S>(with: T?, transform: (Wrapped, T) -> S?) -> S? {
        guard case .some(let first) = self, let second = with else { return nil }
        return transform(first, second)
    }
}
```

**TRUE LAST EDIT :** I highly suggest you to check @Rob Napier answer and its comments, makes a lot of good points on what I’m trying to achieve.

Comment: Why not create a `String` extension that takes two optional `String` values and returns an optional `String`. Then anywhere you need such functionality, you have your simple call to the extension method.

Comment: As I added in a recent edit, I’d want to find a solution that could apply to any `Optional`. I’ll add an edit with a working solution which I find more satisfying than my previous one but still isn’t satisfying enough to me.

Comment: You could always add, for example, a `map(with:transform:)` method to optional, to allow the transform to work with an extra unwrapped optional value. Although of course, this isn't cleanly scaleable to work with an arbitrary number of optional values.

Comment: @Hamish Really like this idea, even though it has the same limitation as my last edit, it feels more elegant.

Comment: You can define it more generally as `func map<T, S>(with: T?, transform: (Wrapped, T) -> S?) -> S?`, and call it alternatively as `first.map(with: second, transform: +)`

Comment: In what way is your original solution not "functional?" You have two bindings and return the result of a pure expression. That is functional programming. Your second solution is more compositional, which is nice. But your later comments seem to suggest you're looking for point-free (though point-free is *very* hard to write in Swift, and generally is not good Swift). Is your point "actual functional programming" or "using tools that often are used in functional languages" or "in a style unfamiliar to imperative programmers?"

Comment: @RobNapier That’s a very good point, used the wrong vocabulary you’re right. I mean using tools often used in functional languages. I wanted to explore other ways to do the same thing using other concepts. My difficulty to express it in words makes it even more obvious I lack knowledge on these subjects. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I'm _sure_ we've dealt with this question here before.

Comment: In functional programming the *first*  thing I would do is to convert the two values into a *list*.

Answer (score 4):

While I think the original code is very good Swift, and what you should use (and there's nothing un-functional about it), the FP tool you want for this is called `sequence` in Haskell. What you're building here is a monad (I know "monad" is always the start of a confusing conversation, but that's precisely what you're building). You want an expression that has a value if all the elements have a value, but no value if any of the elements do not. That's exactly what monads are very commonly used for.

So let's build `sequence`. This unfortunately conflicts with Swift's `sequence`, but I don't really recommend using this tool anyway for this purpose. `if-let` is a much more powerful monad in Swift; it's pretty close to Haskell's do-notation in fact.

```
// I'd never build `sequence` this way. I'd build it with a for-loop in Swift, but 
// to stay super functional...
func sequence<T>(_ elements: [T?]) -> [T]? {
    let result = elements.flatMap{$0}
    return result.count == elements.count ? result : nil
}
```

OK, what do we do with that? Well, this is all very general (as good FP is). It should work equally well for two elements as a hundred elements. So arrays are exactly the tool. And `reduce` lets us turn an array into a value:

```
var concat: String? {
    return sequence([first, second])?.reduce("", +)
}
```

Comment: `joined()` is a simpler way to express `reduce("", +)`. I really like this answer because I had a similar idea (using `contains { $0 == nil }`) but it seemed a bit crazy to create a function for something that Swift can do using an operator (`as?`).

Comment: Fair on both points. I hadn't really played with `[T?]` -> `[T]?` via `as?`. Wow is that feels magical… I always feel weird using `as?` to do actual conversions (not just casting; I have to believe this copies)

Comment: The first rule in functional programming is not to worry about performance :)

Comment: I'm not worried about the performance. I'm worried about the meaning. But I'm probably being over picky about it. I think there have been some discussions of really nailing down what `as?` and `as` mean. But your approach is probably better.

Comment: But hey, any opportunity to discuss monads in a non-ironic context, right? And `reduce` is much more functional than `joined` because…um…it makes lots of temporary values :D

Comment: What if you had to implement the same thing with an arbitrary number of elements each one having its own arbitrary type and resulting in an other unrelated type? I think variadic generics are not part of the language so pretty sure it’s not possible.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible, but more the point, what would it mean? Would would be the type of the result? You can't apply `+` to arbitrary types for instance.

Comment: My goal wasn’t really to apply `+` but more like doing something like `Array.map` does with an arbitrary set of variables. With n variables (types doesn’t play) return one variable. I wanted to do something like this : `(var1, var2).map({ SomeClass(var1, var2) })` in my real project.

Comment: @Fantattitude if `var1` and `var2` are not the same type then it's something that is probably impossible in Swift. You are talking about a functionality that would need a language without strong types. For example, implementing something like that in Javascript would be easy.

Comment: No; this is basically the old JSON-parsing problem that way too much digital ink has been spilled over. The best solution IMO is if-let. You can get ever-more-clever, but it tends to blow up and become less flexible rather than more.

Comment: Kudos to Rob for guessing it had to do with my very own JSON-parsing hell :P

Comment: It's always JSON parsing. Every "can I do this crazy type thing" question is JSON parsing. I now I have a rule: if you're asking for a new Swift language feature, you have to propose a use case *other* than JSON parsing. :D

Comment: (These aren't even the right way to go about fixing Swift to improve JSON parsing. Go is a very statically typed language with a fraction of the type features of Swift and no generics. And it still is capable of doing incredibly type-safe and flexible JSON parsing in a single line of code.)

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a very simple solution:

```
return ([first, second] as? [String])?.joined()
```

How does it work?

The `as?` cast to non-optional array succeeds only if the array does not contain any optionals. Which is basically what you want to check.

If there are no optionals, `joined()` will concat the non-optional items.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what was asked for. Furthermore it's the simplest correct answer given. I hope it's accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
let a: String? = "A"
let b: String? = "B"
let c: String? = "C"

a.concat(b)         // concat #1
a.concat([b,c])     // concat #2
[a,b,c].concat()    // concat #3
[a,b].concat(c)     // concat #4
[a,b].concat([b,c]) // concat #5
```

To have such `concat` functions for `String` or any other type make sure your type conforms to `Concatable`:

```
protocol Concatable {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension String: Concatable {}
```

The rest of the implementation:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Concatable {
    // concat #1
    func concat(_ value: Optional) -> Optional {
        guard let first = self, let second = value else { return nil }
        return first + second
    }
    // concat #2
    func concat(_ values: [Optional]) -> Optional {
        guard let first = self, let second = values.concat() else { return nil }
        return first + second
    }
}

protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype T
    var optional: T? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {
    var optional: Wrapped? {
        return self
    }
}

extension Array where Element: OptionalType, Element.T: Concatable {
    // concat #3
    func concat() -> Element.T? {
        guard count > 0, contains(where: { $0.optional == nil }) == false else { return nil }
        let array = map({ $0.optional! })
        return array.dropFirst().reduce(array[0], +)
    }
    // concat #4
    func concat(_ value: Element.T?) -> Element.T? {
        return concat().concat(value)
    }
    // concat #5
    func concat(_ values: [Element.T?]) -> Element.T? {
        return concat().concat(values.concat())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fully meets your requirements, but I think it is in the right spirit

```
func apply<T>(_ x: T?, y: T?, f: (T, T) -> T?) -> T?
{
    if let x = x, let y = y
    {
        return f(x, y)
    }
    return nil
}

var first: String? = "First"
var second: String? = "Second"

var concat: String? {
    return apply(first, second, +)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to simplify things at point of use in your code.

With that in mind, I would suggest overloading to the + operator. Unfortunately there isn't an underpinning protocol for `+`that I could find, so I made my own:

```
protocol Addable {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

func +<T: Addable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T? {
    guard let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs else {
        return nil
    }
    return lhs + rhs
}

extension String: Addable { }
extension Int: Addable { }
extension Float: Addable { }

let test1: String = "1testing"
let test2: String? = "2testing"
let test3: String? = nil

let realTest = test1 + test2 // 1testing2testing
let nilTest = test1 + test3 // nil

let intTest1: Int = 1
let intTest2: Int? = 2
let intTest3: Int? = nil

let intRealTest = intTest1 + intTest2 // 3
let intNilTest = intTest1 + intTest3 // nil
```

Unfortunately you can't extend protocols (e.g. IntegerArithmetic) to adhere to other protocols so you'll have to add an adherence declaration for all the types you want, but it's identical to normal use, while also allowing custom types to adhere.

Alternately, these 3 would take care of the primary use cases for +:

```
func +(lhs: String?, rhs: String?) -> String? {
    guard let rhs = rhs else {
        return nil
    }
    return lhs?.appending(rhs)
}

func +<T: IntegerArithmetic>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T? {
    guard let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs else {
        return nil
    }
    return lhs + rhs
}

func +<T: FloatingPoint>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> T? {
    guard let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs else {
        return nil
    }
    return lhs + rhs
}
```